# Failed to commit JMS transaction because session is closed

Tags: java, ejb, jms, ibm-mq, mq

In march we updated our websphere mq from version 6 to 7. Since we did this every month one transaction get lost while our application tries to put a message on a MQ queue. We get this error:

> [8/1/12 11:37:53:163 MEST] 00000361 LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0016E:
>   Resource JMS$QueueConnectionFactory$JMSManagedConnection@1276 failed
>   to complete. Exception stack trace follows:
>   javax.transaction.xa.XAException  at
>   com.ibm.ejs.j2c.LocalTransactionWrapper.commit(LocalTransactionWrapper.java:283)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.LocalTransaction.LocalTranCoordImpl.complete(LocalTranCoordImpl.java:942)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.LocalTransaction.LocalTranCoordImpl.complete(LocalTranCoordImpl.java:830)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.LocalTransaction.LocalTranCoordImpl.end(LocalTranCoordImpl.java:1424)
>     at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.commit(TranStrategy.java:891)   at
>   com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.postInvoke(TranStrategy.java:230)    at
>   com.ibm.ejs.csi.NotSupported.postInvoke(NotSupported.java:133)    at
>   com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.postInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:570)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:4558)
>     at com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:111)
>     at com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:136)
>     at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.run(ServerSession.java:567)
>     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604) Caused
>   by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: Failed to
>   commit transaction    at
>   com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSCMUtils.mapToResourceException(JMSCMUtils.java:176)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedSession$JMSLocalTransaction.commit(JMSManagedSession.java:1209)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.j2c.LocalTransactionWrapper.commit(LocalTransactionWrapper.java:263)
>     ... 12 more Caused by:
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSCC0020: This
>   session is closed. An application called a method that must not be
>   used after the session is closed. Ensure that the session is not
>   closed before calling the method.     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:313)
>     at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:388)
>     at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:104)
>     at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.State.checkNotClosed(State.java:145)
>     at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.checkNotClosed(JmsSessionImpl.java:2479)
>     at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.commit(JmsSessionImpl.java:516)
>     at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.commit(MQSession.java:214)  at
>   com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedSession$JMSLocalTransaction.commit(JMSManagedSession.java:1203)
>     ... 13 more .

Our application isn't designed to handle the rollback action and so the message is lost.
I would like to know what is causing this problem since the upgrade and what we could do about it.

The java code we are using is:

```
public void sendMessage(QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory, Queue queue, String text, int priority) throws JMSException{
        QueueConnection connection = null;

        try {   
            connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
            connection.start();

            QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            QueueSender sender = session.createSender(queue);

            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);
            sender.send(message);

        } finally {
            if (connection!=null) 
                connection.close();
        }
    }
```

Kind Regards,

Tom

Comment: If it happens just once per month is there something about the message that we should know before trying to guess the cause?  
Your exception details indicate (to me) that the problem occurs in post-send (possibly acknowledgement generation?). You are attempting to close a connection immediately after send(). BTW: adding some error handling in your code above might help too.

Comment: There is nothing special about the message. On daily basis we handle 100000 messages with the same format. We can't find any similarities between the moments we get this error. I haven't been able to recreate it also. So it's hard to find out what is really causing this issue.

Comment: As I mentioned adding some error handling (logging) in your code above may help you. 1) Are the messages resulting in error valid? Are they considerably longer than the average? Do they have circular dependencies? The list of possible causes is nearly endless.

Comment: It's indeed a long list of possible causes. I've been searching on it for a long time now and I can't find any reason why 1 message in those millions get lost. The error is catched and the logging I get you can read in my question above. The code worked for several years without problems, but since we upgraded to MQ v7 we have lost about 10 messages in 7 months. It's always on a busy moment with a lot of incoming messages. But we have 4 of those busy moments each day.

Comment: You have a PMR opened on this?

Comment: No, I only added a post to the forum.

Comment: Hi,We are facing similar issue. can you please share the solution (if any)?